# Cannot get rid of Safari's image border

Tags: safari

This is driving me nuts — I cannot place the image in src="", because border-radius will then fail. So, I moved it to background: url(), but then Safari keeps pushing this annoying border towards my face. How can I get rid of it ...?!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<img style="width: 500px; height: 500px">
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure about the border radius? This works for me:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<body>
    <img src="test.png" style="border-radius: 10px"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Rendering:

[image: in Safari]

Safari 5.0.3 (6533.19.4), the default 10.6.5 browser.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get rid of the border set it in CSS file, do something like:
set all the images borderless

```
img {border:none}
```

or using a CSS class

```
img.nobrdr {border:none}
```

or specifying the container like on of these

```
#container img {border:none}

.container img {border:none}
```

also specifying a class inside the container

```
.container img.nobrdr {border:none}
```